How to import one .proto file into another?
I'm trying to import one of my proto files into another that is present in the same folder.
My folder structure is as given below:
web/proto/
├── messages.proto
├── messages_v1.proto
└── README.md
web/server/my_package/protobuf/
├── __init__.py
├── messages_pb2.py
└── messages_v1_pb2.py


I'm trying to import messages.proto into messages_v1.proto file.
I tried adding the below import statement in the messages_v1 file, but it is not working.

messages.proto
syntax = "proto3";

message A {
  string i = 1
  string j = 2
}



messages_v1.proto
syntax = "proto3";

import "web/proto/messages.proto";

message B {
  A x = 3
}


Also, I want to later compile them into .py file and for that, I use the below command, correct me if I'm wrong.
web$ protoc -I=./proto --python_out=./server/my_package/protobuf/ ./proto/messages_v1.proto --experimental_allow_proto3_optional

When I run this command I get the below errors
web/proto/messages.proto: File not found.
messages_v1.proto:5:1: Import "web/proto/messages.proto" was not found or had errors.
messages_v1.proto:8:5: "A" is not defined.

There are a few restrictions that I have and they are

I can only use protobuf-compiler version is 3.15.8. I cannot upgrade or downgrade.
I cannot move the files around or rename them


According to protoc --help, there's no = after -I. You may also try and pass messages.proto as an input file as well. Other than that, you approach looks sound. Might just be a minor typo. You might [edit] and clarify what "it is not working" means. It's not a very helpful error description.

what does "not working" mean? I suspect this is just the -I=... error; note that there is also import public if the problem is related to transitive visibility

Sorry for that incomplete question guys. I have updated it now. @Friedrich

Before the edit, you had import "messages.proto" which is correct, AFAIK. After your edit, you prefixed it with a path.

I just verified I get the same error with import "path/to/messages.proto" but everything works fine with import "messages.proto". I'm voting to close as "caused by a typo". Please [edit] and clarify if I'm mistaken.

Hi @Friedrich, thank you for the help, it did work, but only after clearing all my caches and creating a new environment without any changes whatsoever. AFAIK cache should not affect this, but anyway it worked and thank you so much

This is a tricky feature of Protobuf.
There are 2 key aspects: folder paths and package (paths)
Folder paths correspond to the file structure on your machine.
.
└── web
    └── proto <----- Proto Path

Protobuf package names are conventionally (!) mapped to folder paths too.
For example google.protobuf.Timestamp one of the Well-known Types (WKTs) is (by contention) stored in the folder google/protobuf/Timestamp.proto (such that the package name is mapped to a folder name).
These WKTs are located alongside ./bin/protoc in a include folder. NOTE the include folder is the proto path in this case and protoc will look for google.protobuf.Timestamp in the folder beneath include called google/protobuf. The name Timestamp.proto is just a convenience. The file could be called Foo.proto.
In your example, you're using the global namespace (no package) so your protos are directly under the proto path:
.
└── web
    ├── proto
    │   ├── messages.proto
    │   └── messages_v1.proto
    └── server
        └── my_package
            └── protobuf

And your protoc command should be:
PROTO_PATH="${PWD}/web/proto"

protoc \
--proto_path=${PROTO_PATH} \
--python_out=${PWD}/web/server/my_package/protobuf/ \
--pyi_out=${PWD}/web/server/my_package/protobuf/ \
${PROTO_PATH}/messages_v1.proto \
--experimental_allow_proto3_optional

This yields:
.
└── web
    ├── proto
    │   ├── messages.proto
    │   └── messages_v1.proto
    └── server
        └── my_package
            └── protobuf
                └── messages_v1_pb2.py


The long flag --proto_path is more consistent than the short -I
You must define proto_path's for each distinct folder path (excluding the package paths). I use ${PWD} for clarity.
When you reference messages_v1.proto, you must provide a proto path and it must map to one of the --proto_path values.
Consider using the --pyi_out flag (plugin) too to generate type hints.

Protobuf Python is a little awkward in that Protobuf package names aren't mapped to Python modules. In your case, you don't use a package but you must (as always) create __init__.py to create modules for the generated code in the sub-folders.
